# How to run a controller after startup execution finishes?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

Working on .net core app, I have a controller which grabs tokens from API endpoints and save it in cache. Now this controller needs to run after `UseMvc()` and before `UseSpa()` in `Startup.Configure`. Can I run controller like this or is there any better approach to do this.

I'm very new to `.net core` any hints or links will be helpful.

The controller that needs to run:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TokensHelperController : AppBaseController
    {
        public TokensHelperController(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache memoryCache, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory) : base(configuration, memoryCache, clientFactory)
        {

        }

        public static async Task<Token> GetToken(Uri authenticationUrl, Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(authenticationCredentials);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(authenticationUrl, content);

            if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }

            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Token token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(responseString);

            return token;
        }

        public IActionResult GetAccessToken()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials_sb = Configuration.GetSection("EX1:Credentials").GetChildren().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            Token token_sb = GetToken(new Uri(Configuration["EX1:URL"]), authenticationCredentials_sb).Result;

            _cache.Set("sb", token_sb.AccessToken);

            return Ok();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Make the controller a service and run it in startup?

Comment: is it possible for you show any example

Comment: You shouldn't be running a controller at startup, if you want initialisation code, then do that in the startup. Controllers require all sort of things such as a request context that you don't have.

Comment: @DavidG what you recommend? I need to run that code at the beginning of the app cycle it should not return anything it just needs to run once.

Comment: You should extract the business(e.g. the part you need to execute after startup ) and put it into a shared place(like a service) and call this service from both controller and startup.

Comment: @ilkerkaran can you give any example code?

Comment: @JKLM first YOU! (= if you could provide your codebase I can try my best

Comment: @JKLM I Suppose you want to invoke `GetAccessToken()` right?

Comment: @ilkerkaran `GetToken` too `GetAccessToken()` needs  `GetToken`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the cache logic from the controller and put it into a service and an interface ofc.

```
public interface ITokenService{
    void GetAccessToken();
    Task<Token> GetToken(Uri authenticationUrl, Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials)
}


public class TokenService : ITokenService
{
    public TokenService(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache memoryCache, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory) : base(configuration, memoryCache, clientFactory)
    {
    //set the injected values here like configuration etc.
    }

    public void GetAccessToken()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials_sb = Configuration.GetSection("EX1:Credentials").GetChildren().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        Token token_sb = GetToken(new Uri(Configuration["EX1:URL"]), authenticationCredentials_sb).Result;
        _cache.Set("sb", token_sb.AccessToken);
    }

    public async Task<Token> GetToken(Uri authenticationUrl, Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(authenticationCredentials);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(authenticationUrl, content);

        if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
            throw new ApplicationException(message);
        }

        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Token token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(responseString);

        return token;
    }
}

public class TokenService : ITokenService
{
GetAccessToken()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials_sb = Configuration.GetSection("EX1:Credentials").GetChildren().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            Token token_sb = GetToken(new Uri(Configuration["EX1:URL"]), authenticationCredentials_sb).Result;

            _cache.Set("sb", token_sb.AccessToken);
}
```

Now you need to inject ITokenService and use service methods if you want to expose this logic via the controller. and you can use the same service in the startup or anywhere you want. And dont forget to register TokenService in the startup configuration. I hope you get the point. If you struggle at anything please leeave a comment below.

Comment: How do I register a service?

Comment: like this :
`
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();

    ...
}
`

Comment: I added this `services.AddScoped<ITokenService,TokenService>();`  but getting an error - `The type or namespace name 'TokenService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: you need to add using top of the file for TokenService

Comment: its not giving error but its not grabbing the new tokens, I dont think that service is running

Comment: You can debug and find the reason. My main goal is to put you in the right direction. Trying to reach a controller from startup is wrong in so many levels